# How can I get a listview item index when clicking on the item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

For example if I click on the first item it will be at index 0.
If I click on item 15 then the index should be 16.

I tried

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = listView1
        }
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right event or I should use the listView1_Click event ?

And the listView1 does not have any property SelectedIndex.
And last thing is I want to get the item text according to the index of the item I clicked on.

Comment: Don't you mean if you click on item 15 the index should be 14?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ListView.SelectedIndices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property:

```
List<int> selectedIndices = listView1.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

It returns collection of selected indices (because by default you can select several items in listview if you click on items with Ctrl or Shift key pressed). Also note that when you deselect all items, this collection will be empty and things like `listView1.SelectedIndices[0]` will throw `IndexOutOfRange` exception.

But if you will set `MultiSelect` property to `false`. Then this collection will always contain zero or one item. You can use `Count` property of `SelectedIndicesCollection` to check if item was selected:

```
 if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
 {
    int selectedIndex = listView1.SelectedIndices[0];
 }
```

Comment: It's working but i need to click twice on the same item to get the index. The first click return 0 only the second click return the right index.

Comment: @DanielHalfoni did you find source of problem?

Comment: Yes the line was int the SelectedIndex event and once i moved it to the Click event it's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the index of the currently selected item you can do it like this :
 
`int index =  ListView1.FocusedItem.Index`

Comment: There is no property SelectedIndex. I only see SelectedIndices and SelectedItems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the selected indices list you can also do this be item too.

```
listView1.SelectedIndices[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can get listview item object like below

```
ListViewItem lst=(ListViewItem)listView.SelectedItems[0];
```

from that object(lst) you can get the text like below

```
string text=lst.Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices(v=vs.110).aspx), there is still SelectedIndex. In my opinion your event is wrong, but you can still see it by .SelectedIndex. As it was mentioned before.
**UPDATE:** according to the comment, the link is fixed for the correct case.